# parsing list in python

Tags: python, list

I have list in python which has following entries

> name-1
>
> name-2
>
> name-3
>
> name-4
>
> name-1
>
> name-2
>
> name-3
>
> name-4
>
> name-1
>
> name-2
>
> name-3
>
> name-4

I would like remove name-1 from list except its first appearance -- resultant list should look like

> name-1
>
> name-2
>
> name-3
>
> name-4
>
> name-2
>
> name-3
>
> name-4
>
> name-2
>
> name-3
>
> name-4

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Just name-1, or all duplicates? Is preserving order important? I'm guessing it is, but the problem is much easier if it isn't.

Comment: the first item should remain as "name-1" - other than that order of remaining items is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming name-1 denotes "the first element":

```
[names[0]] + [n for n in names[1:] if n != names[0]]
```

EDIT: If the overall goal is to de-duplicate the entire list, just use `set(names)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def remove_but_first( lst, it):
    first = lst.index( it )
    # everything up to the first occurance of it, then the rest of the list without all it
    return lst[:first+1] + [ x for x in lst[first:] if x != it ]

s = [1,2,3,4,1,5,6]
print remove_but_first( s, 1)
```

Comment: lst[:first+1] 
What does this mean?

Comment: a slice from the beginning to the element first+1

Answer (score 2):

Based on Marcelo's solution:

`[name for cnt,name in enumerate(names) if (name != names[0] or cnt > 0)]`

Answer (score 1):

Find the index of the first element you wish to remove, then filter the rest of the list.
The following works in Python 2.5:

```
def removeAllButFirst(elem, myList):
    idx = myList.index(elem)
    return myList[0:idx+1] + filter(lambda x: x != elem, myList[idx+1:])
```

Comment: First three lines could be `idx = myList.index(elem)`

Comment: Also `myList = myList[0:idx] + ...` should probably be `myList = myList[0:idx+1] + ...` (we need to include the first occurence of 'name1').

Comment: Yeah, I just typed in the first thing that came to my head. I couldn't remember the method to find something in a list. I've tested the revised function above, and it does indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = ['name-1', 'name-2', 'name-3', 'name-4', 'name-1', 'name-2', 'name-3', 'name-4', 'name-1', 'name-2', 'name-3', 'name-4']
newlist = filter(lambda x: x != 'name-1', mylist)
newlist.insert(mylist.index('name-1'), 'name-1')
print newlist
['name-1', 'name-2', 'name-3', 'name-4', 'name-2', 'name-3', 'name-4', 'name-2', 'name-3', 'name-4']
```